# Dynamicly create RabbitListner in Java RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, listener

i got a case:
I have a class and a metohod inside it, which will be called in runtime with such params (String exchangeName, String routingKey, String queueName). Is it possible to create a listener with this params, wait for a message / or timeout, and then kill a listener. All i found was about annotation for creating listeners. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there is a way for create a listener dynamicly:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setQueueNames("queueName");
container.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
container.setMessageListener(new Consumer(container));
container.start();
```